# angular.toJSON() function/method implementation on node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Is it possible to somehow implement angular.toJSON function/method on node.js server. All I need is to use angular.toJSON().

I got to it due to hash-key error with '$' when writing data to mongo database.

Or maybe there is a function that would replace angular.toJSON...

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

### Here is the full explanation of the problem and the solution:

Angular gives $scope objects in ng-repeat a "&&hashKey" so it can track any changes and if change occurs then it updates DOM. When You send the object to the node server it still has hashKey elemnt inside itself and it has no effect to most of things in node. However when saving $$hashKey to mongo database via mongoose it throws an error that the key of and element in object should not start with '$'.

So all we need is to remove the hash key. There is an angular.toJSON() method that automatically removed $$hashKey from object but it ONLY WORKS ON CLIENT SIDE.

To implement something that would work the same way on node.js ste2425 proposed using JSON.strigify with replacer option. In final I made a function that can be implemented on node.js that works for my problem (do not know if it is a best solution):

```
function angularToJSON(object) {
    replacer = (key, val) => key.startsWith('$$') ? undefined : val;
    var objectReplaced = JSON.stringify(object, replacer);
    return JSON.parse(objectReplaced);
}
```

Comment: You can use the replacer parameter of the native [json.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) to remove fields when converting to JSON.

Comment: Okay, could You post Your answer and elaborate a bit more if not the problem. Will be sure to put it correct. Not sure  what to put in replacer function if I need to delete hash key.

Comment: _angular on node.js server._......No you can't. Node server don't have any DOM so you can't implement angular methods @ node server.

Comment: Okay then I will change the title of this.

Comment: @AVoid See changing the title is not helping at all. You have to put some code which you are trying to fix. So that people can see and suggest you the edits for the question.

Comment: This question does not acutely need any code as example as it's a straight question with know error with angular ng-repeat adding haskkey to every element. (not error when not saving it to mongo)

Comment: I won't post as an answer as i don't know the full inner workings of `toJSON` however here is a simple fiddle to remove properties prefixed with `$$`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/786kdcrc/)

Comment: Post an answer ste2425 I tested and it works good. Thank You very much.

Comment: @AVoid no problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't replicate angulars `toJSON` as i'm not entirely sure of its inner workings.

However if you want to filter/sanitize an object whilst is being serialized you can use a replacer method available to the standard [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)

```
const obj = {
    one: 10,
    $$two: 'ignore',
    three: {
      $$four: 'troll',
      five: 50
    },
    array: [{
        $$tt: 10,
        bob: 5
      },
      5
    ]
  },
  replacer = (key, val) => key.startsWith('$$') ? undefined : val;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, replacer));

// {"one":10,"three":{"five":50},"array":[{"bob":5},5]}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/786kdcrc/1/)

**Note** I'm sure ive read that key could be `undefined` in some circumstances but couldn't find it on the MDN or replicate it in the fiddle, that could be for de-serializing. Just FYI really.